# Nginx Ingress returns 502 Bad Gateway on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, plotly-dash, nginx-ingress, amazon-eks

I have a Kubernetes cluster deployed on AWS (EKS). I deployed the cluster using the “eksctl” command line tool. I’m trying to deploy a Dash python app on the cluster without success. The default port for Dash is 8050. For the deployment I used the following resources:

- pod
- service (ClusterIP type)
- ingress

You can check the resource configuration files below:

**pod-configuration-file.yml**

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: dashboard-app
  labels:
    app: dashboard
spec:
  containers:
    - name: dashboard
      image: my_image_from_ecr
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8050
```

**service-configuration-file.yml**

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: dashboard-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: dashboard
  ports:
    - port: 8050 # exposed port
      targetPort: 8050
```

**ingress-configuration-file.yml (host based routing)**

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.my_domain
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: dashboard-service
          servicePort: 8050
        path: /
```

I followed the steps below:

```
kubectl apply -f pod-configuration-file.yml
kubectl apply -f service-configuration-file.yml
kubectl apply -f ingress-confguration-file.yml
```

I also noticed that the pod deployment works as expected:

```
kubectl logs my_pod:
```

and the output is:

```
Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

 Warning: This is a development server. Do not use app.run_server
 in production, use a production WSGI server like gunicorn instead.

 * Serving Flask app "annotation_analysis" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
```

You can see from the ingress configuration file that I want to do host based routing using my domain. For this to work, I have also deployed an nginx-ingress. I have also created an “A” record set using Route53
that maps the “dashboard.my_domain” to the nginx-ingress:

```
kubectl get ingress
```

and the output is:

```
NAME                           HOSTS                                            ADDRESS.           PORTS.   AGE                                                            
dashboard-ingress         dashboard.my_domain                  nginx-ingress.elb.aws-region.amazonaws.com   80      93s
```

Moreover,

```
kubectl describe ingress dashboard-ingress
```

and the output is:

```
Name:             dashboard-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          nginx-ingress.elb.aws-region.amazonaws.com
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host                                            Path  Backends
  ----                                            ----  --------
  host.my-domain  
                                              /   dashboard-service:8050 (192.168.36.42:8050)
Annotations:                                      
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: false
                                              
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
                                              
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: false
Events:                                           <none>
```

Unfortunately, when I try to access the Dash app on the browser, I get a
**502 Bad Gateway** error from the nginx. Could you please help me because my Kubernetes knowledge is limited.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you checking your service http://dashboard.my_domain/ ?

Comment: I type dashboard.my_domain on browser. See "kubectl get ingress". The problem is really weird. I followed exactly the same process for a "Flask server (port 5000)" and it works. Thanks for your help btw.

Answer (score 1):

It had nothing to do with Kubernetes or AWS settings. I had to change my python Dash code from:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

to:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True).
```

The addition of  ***host='0.0.0.0'*** did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to check whether any other service is exposed at path `/` on the same host.

Secondly, try removing `rewrite-target` annotation. Also can you please update your question with output of `kubectl describe ingress <ingress_Name>`

I would also suggest you to use `backend-protocol` annotation with value as `HTTP` (default value, you can avoid using this if dashboard application is not SSL Configured, and only this application is served at the said host.) But, you may need to add this if multiple applications are served at this host, and create one Ingress with `backend-protocol: HTTP` for non SSL services, and another with `backend-protocol: HTTPS` to serve traffic to SSL enabled services.

For more information on `backend-protocol` annotation, kindly refer [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#backend-protocol) link.

I have often faced this issue in my Ingress Setup and these steps have helped me resolve it.

Comment: Hi @adityajalkhare. Thanks for helping me. I removed the rewrite-target annotation. Moreover, there's no other service exposed at  /  but the problem is not solved. I just added the "kubectl describe ingress" output. Hope it helps.

Comment: Try hitting your dashboard URL once and look to the logs of Nginx Ingress Controller Pod. I usually get the error message there if something is acting up. Can you please cross check 2 things, 1. Domain in your ingress.yml and `kubectl describe Ingress` command is different, maybe it's a mistake while generalizing output for public. 2. Try to Configure dashboard service/application at some other context path like `/dashboard` and then try

Comment: It's full of "Connection refused" messages.

Comment: I've worked very little with AWS, but I used to setup a rule in one of the security tabs to allow traffic on specific ports, please check if that's blocked or allowed. I don't really remember it as it was more than a year ago, maybe you could understand what I'm trying to say. I've been working on AKS mainly, sorry!

Comment: @P.Str ah yes! the host wasn't defined in code. Glad you worked it out!